# error while performing sqoop - merge

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I was trying to sqoop merge two data sets by importing the data from the netezza server.
below are the data sets with the numeric as **id** and letters as **name**:

Both of the below tables are imported from netezza using the commands:

```
sqoop import --connect neteeza_url --username uname --password pwd --table sqoop_merge_1 --hive-import --warehouse-dir hdfs_pth --create-hive-table sqoop_merge_1 -m 1
```

sqoop_merge_1:

```
1,a
2,b
3,c
4,d
5,e
```

sqoop_merge_2:

```
4,z
5,y
```

and the commands are:

```
sqoop merge --new-data hdfs_path/sqoop_merge_2 --onto hdfs_path/sqoop_merge_1 --target-dir hdfs_path/sqoop_merge_output --jar-file jar_file_path/sqoop_merge_class_name.jar --class-name sqoop_merge_class_name --merge-key id
```

I created the jar file by using the codegen command:

```
sqoop codegen --connect netezza_url --username uname --password -pwd --table sqoop_merge_1
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot join values on null key. Did you specify a key column that exists?
```

Tried all the ways i knew but still getting the error.

Please help.

Comment: "--merge-key id", do you have a column called "id" in those datasets?

Comment: yes i do have..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are sure about `id` column existence, it could be an issue due to case-sensitivity.

Check if you specified `ID` in Netezza?

If yes, try with `--merge-key ID`.

Comment: Thanks dev. Netezza was case sensitive and specifying the id in ID worked out. Didn't think in this way as I created the table in lower case itself.